# Eclipse DS-5:An error was encountered when searching for Android devices

Tags: android-ndk, adb, ds-5

I'm using ARM's tool DS-5(to debug android NDK apps), follow this doc:http://www.arm.com/zh/products/tools/software-tools/ds-5/community-edition/ds-5-community-edition-debug.php

Get a error says:

> An error was encountered when searching for Android devices: Error in
>   get_devices: 'adb' ²»ÊÇÄÚ²¿»òÍâ²¿ÃüÁî£¬Ò²²»ÊÇ¿ÉÔËÐÐµÄ³ÌÐò
>   »òÅú´¦ÀíÎÄ¼þ¡£

Any one use DS-5,any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of a device you are trying to debug on?

Can you list devices on console?

```
$ adb devices
```

Also seems to be a path problem i think
I remember hitting a similar one and if you are a windows user adb.exe should be on your path as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the cause is, but if I had to guess, it something todo with the language your running DS-5/adb in. I suspect it's not coping with the encoding of coming back from adb. What language is it running in? Any chance you could switch to English?